# Replicate CSS3 sliding content transitions with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, transition

A project I'm on is happy with the modern code I've developed using CSS3 (below) but want the same effect across two legacy browsers, IE8 (used in my client's office) and IE9. I've tried using the jQuery .animate function (an example below) but I'm wondering whether I'm doing something wrong - jQuery isn't something I normally use! I also know they require it to work with jQuery 1.3.2, which is what's used on the rest of their site, as they've had issues with more modern bits of jQuery breaking other functionality on the pages.

Here is the CSS

```
#sliderOne .content,#sliderOne .image{position:absolute;top:0;left:180px;-webkit-transition:all .8s;-o-transition:all .8s;transition:all, .8s;-moz-transition:all .8s ease-in}
#sliderOne:hover .image{position:absolute;left:0}
#sliderThree .content,#sliderThree .image{position:absolute;top:180px;left:180px;-webkit-transition:all, .8s;-moz-transition:all .8s ease-in;-o-transition:all, .8s;transition:all, .8s}
#sliderFour .sliderTitle{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
#sliderFour .content,#sliderFour .image{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;-webkit-transition:all, .8s;-moz-transition:all .8s ease-in;-o-transition:all, .8s;transition:all, .8s}
#sliderFive .sliderTitle{position:absolute;top:0;left:180px}
#sliderFive .content,#sliderFive .image{position:absolute;top:0;left:180px;-webkit-transition:all, .8s;-moz-transition:all .8s ease-in;-o-transition:all, .8s;transition:all, .8s}
.sliderTitle .right{text-align:right}
.sliderTitle p.number{font-size:6em}
.sliderTitle p.number,#sliderContainer h3,#sliderContainer h4{font-family:cursive}
#sliderContainer .content p,#sliderContainer .content h4{padding:1em}
#sliderOne,#sliderThree,#sliderFive,#sliderOne .content,#sliderThree .content,#sliderFive .content{float:left}
#sliderOne:hover .content,#sliderThree .sliderTitle{position:absolute;top:180px;left:180px}
#sliderTwo .sliderTitle,#sliderSix .sliderTitle{position:absolute;top:180px;left:0}
#sliderTwo .content,#sliderTwo .image,#sliderSix .content,#sliderSix .image{position:absolute;top:180px;left:0;-webkit-transition:all, .8s;-moz-transition:all .8s ease-in;-o-transition:all, .8s;transition:all, .8s}
```

And here's an example of the jQuery I've tried:

```
    $('#sliderTwo').hover(function() {
  $('#sliderTwo .image').animate({top:'=-180px'},600);
});
```

I can provide some of the HTML as well if necessary.

Comment: Please make your CSS readable and explain clearly exactly what animation effect you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like [THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9p5nP/2/)?

```
$('#sliderTwo').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#sliderTwo .image').stop().animate({top:'0px'},600);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('#sliderTwo .image').stop().animate({top:'180px'},600);
});
```

Works in 1.3.2